# Who wrote the "You don't knock" gospel?

Tags: soul

This is a more or less well known song, with famous versions, e.g. by Dolly Parton et al.:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnhNhDwlLyQ

I have seen it credited to Mavis Staples, but I guess there is a previous version.

Oddly enough it does not have a Wikipedia page :O

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The liner notes for Trio credit this to "Roebuck Staples/Wesley Westbrooks".

- Roebuck was "Papa" Staples, the founder of the [Staples Singers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Staple_Singers).
- Wesley has various credits on [discogs](https://www.discogs.com/artist/1288422-Wesley-D-Westbrooks). He was a musician in the jazz and gospel traditions, and subject of a biog by [Dick Weissman](http://www.dickweissman.com/books/books.html)  ("Wes Westbrooks: A Life In and Out of Gospel Music and Jazz") which is mentioned in other books of his, but I can't see in print.